# Laravel livewire, displaying the result of two queries in one grid component

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

I need to display two datasets coming from the same MySQL database table inside a Laravel Livewire grid component. One dataset contains all the entries from the last 20 minutes and one dataset contains all the entries for the last 24 hours.

For grid component I am looking at https://github.com/mediconesystems/livewire-datatables

The table has the following structure:

ID: Integer
inserted_on: datetime
origination: string
field_count: integer

What would be the best way to achieve this in Laravel with Livewire?